# Binary Searching in Java

Tags: java

I'm making a program that outputs read double numbers from a data file into an array,  asks the user for both a search number and a replacement value, output the original array, if that value was found, and the new array. I've complied the code several times and tried to work around this annoying error that happens in the

```
list = addData.toArray( new Double[0] );
```

but its not working :( I've almost got the program done, it should do this:

ex:

What are you searching for? ==> 6.17
Replace it with ? ==> 3.21

Original Data:  [4.67,  2.98,  1.10,  9.73,  5.73]

Search Result:  6.17 was not found in the array.

New Array:  [4.67,  2.98,  1.10,  9.73,  5.73]

Is there a way to fix this problem so my program can work ?

```
package solution;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Java6002 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Environment().run();
    }
}

class Environment {
    private int[] list;

    public Environment() {
        try {
            Scanner fScan = new Scanner(new File("Java6002a.dat"));
            ArrayList<Double> addData = new ArrayList<Double>();

            while(fScan.hasNext()) {
                addData.add(fScan.nextDouble());
                list = addData.toArray(new Double[0]);
            }       
        }catch(Exception e) { }
    }

    public void run() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(in);
        out.print("What are you searching for? => ");
        double target = scan.nextDouble();

        out.print("Replace it with? => ");
        double update = scan.nextDouble();

        out.println();
        out.println("Original Data: " + this.toString());

        out.print("Search Result: ");
        if(replace(target,update))
            out.println(target + " was found in the array.");
        else
            out.println(target + " was NOT found in the array.");
        out.println();
        out.println("New array: " + this);
    }

    public boolean replace(double t, double w)
    {
        for (int x=0; x<list.length; x++)
        if (list[x] == t)
        {   
            list[x] = w;
            return true;    
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
       String temp="[";
           for(int x=0;x<list.length;x++) temp+=list[x]+",";
        temp+="]";
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? First thing which comes to mind would be to change `int[] list` to `double[] list`, since you are trying to add an array of doubles to an array of int.

Comment: Did you tried using `list = addData.toArray();` (remove argument from method)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the type of list array to `Double`

```
private Double[] list;
```

you are trying to cast list to array but passing the target array datatype to be double but its int.

From [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(T%5B%5D))

> **Collection.toArray(T[] a)**
>
> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this collection;
> the runtime type of the returned array is that of the specified array.